# Find the basis of the intersection of two vector subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I know there is lots of topics about intersection of two vector subspaces and basis but i still dont fully understand how we should handle these question.
So this is my homework:

Suppose U and W are subspaces of $R^3:\\$
$U=[(1,0,-1),(0,1,1)]\\W=[(2,4,0),(0,0,\sqrt{3})]\\$

Find a basis of $U\cap W \\$

So i know $U \cap W$ -> $a_1*(1,0,-1)+a_2*(0,1,1)-b_1*(2,4,0)-b_2*(0,0,\sqrt{3})=0\\$
a possible combination of coefficients $a_1=1,a_2=2,b_1=\frac12,b_2=-\sqrt{3}\\$

then i put the $1*(1,0,-1)+2*(0,1,1)$ in a matrix $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & 2 \\
        -1 & 2  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\\$$

then i bring it to row-achelon form

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & 2 \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\\$$

so Basis=$\{ (1,0,-1),(0,1,1) \}$ (i m not sure if the last vector should be $(0,1,1)$ or $(0,2,2)) $?

So is the solution correct ?

Comment: No, your basis is not a member of $W$, so it can't be an intersection

Comment: I did not follow everything, but unless the subspaces $V,W$ are equal (and U,W are not parallel), their intersection is a line, so the basis should consist of just 1 vector. do you know how to recover the equation of a plane from its basis vectors?

Comment: Also think of the following, @nbdip : if the intersection of two 2-dimensional spaces is a 2-dimensional space, then the intersect **is** one of the two subspaces...

Comment: i m really confused right now @Tim.Ratigan What did you mean by "your basis is not a member of w"
edit:ok i get it. But if i put the other vectors with coefficient b1 and b2 in to the matrix.should that work

Comment: @user99680 do you mean for example for R^2=(1,0)*a+(0,1)*b

Comment: @DonAntonio so the solution was correct ??

Comment: @nbdip , iff $\;U\subset W\;\;or\;\;W\subset U\;$ ...is any of these two true?

Comment: The basis vectors you obtained for your solution cannot be generated by W's basis vectors and therefore cannot be elements of W, which is a contradiction since you claim it is the intersect of U and W.

Comment: @nbdip: just like you can obtain a basis {$v_1,v_2$} from the equation $ax+by+c=d$ , you can go the other way around and obtain an equation $ax+by+cz=d$ from a basis {$v_1,v_2$}.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $U=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix}\lambda+\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}\mu\mid \lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$, $W=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}2\\4\\0\end{pmatrix}\lambda+\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\\sqrt{3}\end{pmatrix}\mu\mid \lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$

For $U\cap W,$ $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1\\\mu_1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\4&0\\0&\sqrt{3}\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_2\\\mu_2\end{bmatrix}$
$$ \lambda_1=2\lambda_2 $$
$$ \mu_1=4\lambda_2 $$
$$ -\lambda_1+\mu_1=\sqrt{3}\mu_2 $$
$$ \Rightarrow\lambda_2=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\mu_2 $$
Thus $U\cap W=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}2\\4\\0\end{pmatrix}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\mu+\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\\sqrt{3}\end{pmatrix}\mu\mid \mu\in\mathbb{R}\right\}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{3}\\2\sqrt{3}\\\sqrt{3}\end{pmatrix}\mu\mid \mu\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$

Note that the magnitude of the basis vector is largely irrelevant, so you can normalize it to make it $\langle1,2,1\rangle$.

Comment: then we could do (1,0,-1)*sqrt(3)m +(0,1,1)*2*(sqrt(3))m aswell right ?

Comment: Why did you equalize them?

Comment: Did you mean W instead of V?

Answer (score 2):

Let me try a comprehensive answer. The [Zassenhaus algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zassenhaus_algorithm) does this job, but it is somehow difficult to explain. Another approach is to remember that [elementary row operations preserve linear dependence between columns of a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354362/why-do-elementary-row-operations-preserve-linear-dependence-between-matrix-colum). Suppose that
$$U=[u_1=(1,0,0,-1),u_2=(0,1,0,-1),u_3=(0,0,1,1)]$$ and $$W=[w_1=(1,0,-1,0),w_2=(0,1,-1,0),w_3=(0,0,0,1)].$$
Note that the generators of $U$ and $W$ are linearly independent, otherwise we could exclude the dependent vectors. Now, form a matrix whose columns are the vectors of U followed by the vectors of W:
$$M=\left[\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 0 \\ 
-1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\  
\end{matrix}\right].
$$
Computing the reduced row echelon form of $M$ we obtain that
$$\text{rref}(M)=\left[\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -\frac{1}{2} \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \frac{1}{2} \\  
\end{matrix}\right].
$$
Therefore we can conclude from the aforementioned fact, that
$$\begin{aligned}
w_2&=-u_1+u_2+w_1 \\
w_3&=-\frac{1}{2}u_1+\frac{1}{2}u_3+\frac{1}{2}w_1
\end{aligned}$$
and that $u_1$, $u_2$, $u_3$ and $w_1$ form a basis of $U+W$.
We cannot say that $w_2$ and $w_3$ form a basis of $U\cap W$, because they are not linear combinations of vectors of $U$, but defining
$$\begin{aligned}
w_2'&:=w_2-w_1 = -u_1+u_2 \\
w_3'&:=w_3-\frac{1}{2}w_1=-\frac{1}{2}u_1+\frac{1}{2}u_3
\end{aligned}$$
we see that $w_2'\in U\cap W$ and $w_3'\in U\cap W$. It is easy to see from general considerations that $w_2'$ and $w_3'$ are linearly independent and from
$$\text{dim}(U+W)+\text{dim}(U\cap W)=\text{dim}(U)+\text{dim}(W),$$
it turns out that they form a basis of $U\cap W$. This procedure can clearly be generalized and even transformed into a proof of the theorem about the dimension of the sum of subspaces.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\{(1,0,-1),(0,1,1), (0,0,\sqrt 3\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ then $U \cup W=\mathbb{R}^3$. So, $\dim (U \cap W)=1$. Moreover we can choose $\{(1,2,1)\}$ a basis of $U \cap W$ because $\{(1,2,1)\} \in U \cap W$.

Comment: Uhh... $\langle 1,1,0\rangle\not\in W$...

Try finding a linear combination of $\langle 2, 4, 0\rangle$ and $\langle 0,0,\sqrt{3}\rangle$ that makes $\langle 1,1,0\rangle$

Comment: Thanks... I'll correct that

Comment: Yes, I did an error computation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is my idea: just like we can obtain a basis from an expression $ax+by+cz=0$ to a basis $(x_0,y_0,z_0),(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ for the plane described by that equation (by using the basic linear -algebra -fact that $ax+by+cz=0$ has 2 free variables; say $ y,z $), we can reverse the process to get an equation $ax+by+cz=0$ when we're given two basis vectors $(x_0,y_0,z_0),(x_1,y_1,z_1)$. Once we have the two planes associated to the given basis in the form $ax+by+cz=0$, we can easily find their intersection.

Then, the plane spanned by $(1,0,-1),(0,1,1)$ is $x-y+z=0$ , and the plane spanned by $(2,4,0),(0,0,\sqrt 3)$ is $4\sqrt 3x-2\sqrt3 y$. It then just comes down to solving the simple system:

$i)x-y+z=0$

$ii)4\sqrt3x-2\sqrt3y=0$

Whose solution is $y=2z$ ; back-substitution in $i$ gives us $x-2z+z=0$ , so $x=z$, and $y=2z$ gives us the line $(x,2x,x)$, spanned by, e.g. $(1,2,1)$