# Show that the $\text{rank}(A)=$ number of pivot elements in $T$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, matrix-rank

**Problem:** Given $A_{m\times n}$ and $T$, where $T$ is the equivalent row-reduced matrix in echelon form.

1. Show that rank$(A)=$ number of pivot elements in $T.$
2. Show that the nulldim$(A)=$ the dimension of $A$ minus the number of pivot elements in $T$.

---

**Attempt:**

**1)** Since the matrix $A$ is of type $m\times n$, it follows that dim$(A)=n.$ Denote the number of pivot elements in $T$ by $p$. I need to show that rank$(A)=p.$

Saying that $T$ is the echelon form, row-reduced equivalent  of $A$ is the equivalent of saying that ker$(A)=$ker$(T)$. Does it to suffice to state this? Isn't it true that if the kernels are equal, it follows that their ranks are equal?

**2)** Here, I'm supposed to show that nulldim$(A)=p-r,$ which is the rank-nullity theorem. any simple proof for this?

Comment: What is your definition of rank A in this case?

Comment: For $\mathrm{rank}(A)=p$, consider the linear relations between columns. These do not change by row operations. Check linear relations between columns in $T$. For $\mathrm{nulldim}(A)=n-p$, solve the homogeneous linear system $Tx=0$, and write the solution in terms of free variables. Then you can see that number of free variables is $n-p$ and that is also $\mathrm{nulldim}(A)$.

Comment: @i707107 - But does the answer "the linear relations between columns does not change by row operations" suffice? Shouldn't one show this? How can I solve $Tx=0$ when $m$ and $n$ is not known?

Answer (score 1):

No, the linear relations between columns do change by row operations. Only the *dimension* of the column space is preserved. You can read some of the explanations [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354362/why-do-elementary-row-operations-preserve-linear-dependence-between-matrix-colum). This is a comment of user **lhf** from the same link that sums it up:

> Elementary row operations do not change the row space of a matrix but they do change the column space; only the *dimension* of the column space is preserved.

Hence, I believe the best way to prove question $1$ is by first showing that column rank of $A$ is equal to row rank of $A$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Proofs_that_column_rank_.3D_row_rank) for the proof). And since by doing row operations, the row space do not change, which follows row rank $A$ = number of pivot elements in $T$. But since row rank $A$ = column rank $A$ so we are done.

For question $2$, we know that nullspace of $A$ is set of vectors $\mathbf{x}$ so $\mathbf{Ax}=0$. Let $A=(a_{i,j})_{m \times n}, \mathbf{x}=(x_{i,1})_{1 \le i \le n}$ and denote $\mathbf{a_i}$ as the $i$th column vector of $\mathbf{A}$. We can rewrite $\mathbf{Ax}=0$ as following 
$$x_1 \mathbf{a_1}+x_2\mathbf{a_2}+ \ldots + x_n\mathbf{a_n}=0. \tag{1}$$

WLOG, let $\{ \mathbf{a_1}, \ldots, \mathbf{a_k} \}$ be basis of column space then $k= \text{rank }A$.  This follows all column vectors $\mathbf{a_j} \; (j>k)$ can be written as linear combination of $\{\mathbf{a_1},\mathbf{a_2}, \ldots, \mathbf{a_k}\}$, or $\mathbf{a_j}= \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_{i,j}\mathbf{a_i}$ for $j \ge k+1$. Combining with $(1)$, we obtain $$\left( x_1- \sum_{i=k+1}^n \alpha_{1,i}x_i \right)\mathbf{a_1}+\ldots+\left( x_k- \sum_{i=k+1}^n \alpha_{k,i}x_i \right)\mathbf{a_k}=0.$$
But since $\{ \mathbf{a_1}, \ldots, \mathbf{a_k} \}$ are linearly independent so that means $x_j= \sum_{i=k+1}^n \alpha_{j,i}x_i$ for all $1 \le j \le k$. This follow, any solution $\mathbf{x}$ of $\mathbf{Ax}=0$ can be written as 
$$\mathbf{x}=(x_i)_{m \times 1}= x_{k+1} \begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_{1,k+1} \\ 
\vdots \\ 
\alpha_{k,k+1} \\
1_{k+1} \\
0_{k+2} \\
\vdots \\
0_n
\end{pmatrix}+x_{k+2} \begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_{1,k+2} \\ 
\vdots \\ 
\alpha_{k,k+2} \\
0_{k+1} \\
1_{k+2} \\
0_{k+3} \\
\vdots \\
0_n
\end{pmatrix}+ \ldots + x_n\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_{1,n} \\ 
\vdots \\ 
\alpha_{k,n} \\
0_{k+1} \\
\vdots \\
1_n
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Note that these $n-k$ column vectors are linearly independent so that mean they spans the nullspace of $A$. This follows $\text{dim} N(A)=n-k$. We also know that $k= \text{rank }A$ so we are done.